# Превратить в массив

Tags: php

Как лучше превратить вот такую переменную в юзабельный массив?

```
{\"au_a_logic1\":\"2000\",\"au_a_logic2\":\"3000\",\"au_b_logic1\":\"500\",\"au_b_logic2\":\"1000\",\"au_b_logic3\":\"2000\",\"au_b_logic4\":\"5500\",\"au_b_logic5\":\"7500\",\"au_b_logic6\":\"20000\",\"au_b_logic7\":\"50000\",\"au_b_logic8\":\"100000\",\"au_c_logic1\":\"2.5\",\"au_c_logic2\":\"3.5\",\"au_c_logic3\":\"5.5\",\"au_c_logic4\":\"7.5\",\"au_c_logic5\":\"15\",\"au_c_logic6\":\"20\",\"au_f_logic1\":\"0.54\",\"au_f_logic2\":\"0.48\",\"au_f_logic3\":\"0.48\",\"au_f_logic4\":\"0.48\",\"au_f_logic5\":\"0.48\",\"au_f_logic6\":\"0.48\",\"au_d_logic1\":\"1.5\",\"au_d_logic2\":\"1.7\",\"au_d_logic3\":\"2.5\",\"au_d_logic4\":\"2.7\",\"au_d_logic5\":\"3\",\"au_d_logic6\":\"3.6\",\"au_e_logic1\":\"50000\",\"au_e_logic2\":\"50000\",\"gotoemail\":\"\",\"jqueryswitch\":\"1\",\"layout\":\"_:default\"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте функцию [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php)

Код на [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/ZohPOT)

Comment: Только, если именно массив, то второй параметр указать:

    json_decode($json_str, true);

Comment: Глупый вопрос, но у меня не получилось вывести переменные из массива.
Как например вывести "au_e_logic1"?

Comment: `$obj = json_decode($string);`

`var_dump($obj->au_e_logic1);`